# Images display in gridview using JSON parsing in android

Tags: android, json, gridview

I am new in android apps development. Can anybody suggest me how to display images in a gridview using JSON parsing in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this class in your project: JsonParser

```
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {

            URL aURL = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Buffered is always good for a performance plus.
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize =5;
            // Decode url-data to a bitmap.
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis, null, options);

            // Close BufferedInputStream
            bis.close();

            // Close InputStream
            is.close();

            return bitmap;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

in main activity:-
add grid view and set adapter
call the asyntask with your URL

```
ImageDownloader d=new ImageDownloder();
Bimap b=d.execute("url").get();
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);// grid view ti view all photos
AdapterForPics adap = new AdapterForPics(Arraylist, Context);
grid.setAdapter(adap);
```

Answer (score 3):

what exactly you want to do because json parsing and display images in gridview are two diffrent things. either you want to fatch image from server and use json parsing to parse  URLs .Or make your question clear to understand by everyone.